MongoDB Atlas connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError, despite IP whitelisted and successful mongosh/Compass connections
Issue: I'm working on a Node.js backend using MongoDB Atlas and Mongoose. The server is running fine on port 8080, but I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to the MongoDB cluster:
MongoDB connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/


Steps I’ve Taken:
Whitelisted IPs: My current IP is whitelisted, and I’ve even set the network access to allow connections from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0).
Successful Connection in Other Tools:
I can connect to the database using mongosh without any issues.
MongoDB Compass is also able to connect successfully.
Network Access: I’ve verified that the cluster’s network access is properly configured.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.0sgfn.mongodb.net/eateasy?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0`
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected...");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection error:", err);
  });


What I’ve Tried:
Restarted the server multiple times.
Rechecked my IP whitelist settings.
Verified that the URI credentials are correct.
Questions:
Why would I be able to connect through mongosh and MongoDB Compass but not via my Node.js backend using Mongoose?
Are there any additional network settings or configurations I might be missing for this connection to work?

Are you using the exact same connection string (uri) in mongosh that you're using in node.js ?

Does your password has any special characters (i.e .$ : / ? # [ ] @) or maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

@Kartik here is the complete file for mongoose connection in Node.js
mongoose.js config file:
Just change the environment variables with your credentials.
"use strict";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("../config");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
mongoose.pluralize(null); // STOP auto pluralize
require("dotenv").config();

async function connectToDB() {

   try {
    let mongoObj = config.db.mongo;

    await mongoose.connect(mongoObj.fullUri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error: "));
    db.once("open", function () {
      console.log(`MongoDB connected successfully: ${mongoObj.dbName}`, mongoObj.fullUri);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("MongoDB connection error:", error);
    throw new Error("MongoDB connection error occurred.");
  }

}

module.exports = connectToDB;

Please try with this code, hopefully this will fix your problem.
